# How to set variable with special characters in Robot Framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, robotframework, special-characters

I am setting a variable with String which has some special characters.

Here's below the code snippet for the same

`${message}    Set variable      < & Hi, how can I help? > " '`

Also the same message is being sent in logs and it is being validated using the grep command.
But I'm facing issue while validating the same. I tried escaping few characters in set variable. Also tried to match the number of double quotes and single quote. But no help

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. It's not clear what you mean by _"being validated using the grep command"_.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this syntax
${escaped} =    Regexp Escape   ${original}